# Get a single rating against particular id by finding nearest date from a series of dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Dataframe 1 has two columns (customer_id, date and rating) and Dataframe 2 has (customer_id, start_date, instrument_id). The function needs to run such that the instrument_id in DF2 includes rating for date closest to start_date.

DF1:

```
customer_id   date    rating
84952608    31-Mar-20   4-
84952608    31-Dec-19   3-
84952608    30-Jun-19   4
84952608    31-Mar-19   5-
```

DF2:

```
Instrument_id   customer_id start_date
000LCLN190240003    84952608    31-Mar-2019
```

Result DF:

```
Instrument_id   customer_id rating
000LCLN190240003    84952608    5-
```

5- selected since start_date is closest to date

I got a working sample, however the compute time is significant in this case. For around 3k records it takes around 40-50 seconds
DF2 is exposure and DF1 is file

```
for w in range(len(exposure)): 
        max_preceeding_date = file.loc[(file['customer_id']==exposure.loc[w,'customer_id']) & (file['date']<=exposure.loc[w,'start_date']),['rating','date']].sort_values('date', ascending=False)
value = max_preceeding_date.iloc[0,0]
```

I also tried using df.merge to first merge both the dataframes, however unable to figure out how to use groupby to get the final output.

Appreciate your time and effort in helping on this one.

Comment: *closest* or "equal to" ?

Comment: It has to be closest, given the nature of the data.

Comment: define "closest", cause right now it's an exact match, both 31-mar-2019

Answer (score 0):

Merging dataframes and comparing *datetime* objects:

```
In [254]: res_df = df2.merge(df1, how='left', on='customer_id')                                                         

In [255]: res_df[['start_date', 'date']] = res_df[['start_date', 'date']].apply(lambda s: pd.to_datetime(s))            

In [256]: res_df[res_df['date'] <= res_df['start_date']].sort_values(['start_date', 'date'], ascending=[False, False]).d
     ...: rop(['start_date', 'date'], axis=1)                                                                           
Out[256]: 
      Instrument_id  customer_id rating
3  000LCLN190240003  84952608     5-
```

Comment: I tested the code. However, i am getting 4 rows in the resultant array given the merge operation would have created 4 rows

Comment: @Zedi10, so slice the `0` item